# Should .NET MVC 3 actions trigger w3wp.exe to generate Process Monitor "PATH NOT FOUND" and "NAME NOT FOUND" errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, process, iis-7.5

If I create an out-of-the-box ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application (non-empty, Razor, no unit tests) and deploy it to an IIS 7.5 site (.NET 4, Integrated Pipeline), every controller action I trigger causes a ton of "name not found" and "path not found" errors in procmon.

The w3wp.exe process is trying to visit file system locations that the MVC Routing engine should pick up and handle.  This is a small portion of the procmon log after clicking the "LogOn" link one time only:

[image: Process Monitor Output]

Is this expected behavior?  It doesn't feel right to me.

I came across this because my server CPU utilization was pegged at 100%.  One of my calls was happening frequently enough (causing the "path not found" error) that it was eating up CPU.  **As soon as I created a file system folder at the path it was trying to access, the CPU utilization dropped to 0%** (~85 concurrent users on the site in both cases).

Comment: Interesting. Thing is, somewhere the web server *will* need to check whether the path is a physical one or whether to invoke the MVC routing functions. Perhaps the checking for this is more costly than catching the lower level PATH NOT FOUND exception?

Comment: Another thought on this: You could try asking on ServerFault; perhaps an IIS expert could tell you something?

Comment: Asked on Server Fault as well:  http://serverfault.com/questions/251856/should-net-mvc-3-actions-trigger-w3wp-exe-to-generate-process-monitor-path-not

Comment: Have you upgraded to MVC 3 RTM (which includes WebPages 1.0 RTM)? This uncached behavior might be a result of running a pre-release build.

Comment: Also, to be clear, you haven't added anything to the project, right? You just unfolded a brand new MVC 3 project and hit Run?

Comment: We're running 3.0.20105.0.  Is that the RTM release?  Also, yes, I haven't added anything to the project at all.  Out-of-the-box...

Comment: I can't reproduce this with MVC 3 RTM, Windows 7, IIS 7.5. A refresh of /Account/LogOn only shows a couple hits against web.config files, as well as some probing of Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Comment: I created a new OOTB MVC3 web app, published to a new IIS 7.5 site on a new Win2008 R2 server, and it's still happening for me.  If I refresh /Account/LogOn multiple times, eventually it only triggers a single "PATH NOT FOUND" in procmon per refresh, but if I then visit /Account/Register, and come right back to /Account/LogOn, procmon looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/pthwM.png.  That screenshot is the output from one visit to /Account/LogOn.

Comment: hello. I am having teh same problem, did you found a soluction? thanks

Comment: This behavior never went away, but I fixed the underlying performance problem, which was my primary concern.  I would still like to know why all this activity happens...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably in the Debug configuration. When DEBUG is defined, MVC does a ton of file probing which it doesn't do in Release configuration (Release uses a file cache, so you only pay this cost the first time). As a general rule, you should *always* use Release configuration for performance testing.

Comment: Great thought, but I deployed the application in Release mode for that very reason.  The behavior still occurs (and it has been occurring on a live production site in Release model for a while now).

Comment: If you can reproduce it locally, build with the MVC source code and trace through the view engine to see why it's skipping the cache.

Answer (score 0):

10 years late... Have you tried [setting allowSubDirConfig to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099369/6254070)?

It's not necessarily right or wrong. Microsofts default is for the w3wp.exe worker to check those directories so you can have a different web.config than the root application (e.g. a child application). It seems like an ancient default, because if you're deploying Microsoft apis you almost always want the IIS worked to hand off routing to dotnet/dotnetcore immediately. I'm not an IIS admin though, so I probably have an incomplete understanding. We found we gained a slight performance increase with the configuration set to false.